# How to use I-Value in for-loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, for-loop, nodemailer

Hi I am playing around with javascript and firebase but running into an issue.

I want to sent the same email to every email listed in my datebase after the database entry hast been created:

[image]

If I use the code without the for-loop everything works fine:

```
to: snap.data().email,
```

I tried a few ways to use the i-value as an argument - one of them not working is in the code below:

```
to: snap.data().email.concat(i.toString()),
```

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

      for(var i = 1; i <= snap.data().number; i++) {
        const mailOptions = {

            from: `***********`,
            to: snap.data().email.concat(i.toString()),
            subject: `From ${snap.data().name}`,
            html: `<h1>Me ${snap.data().name} </h1>
                                <p>
                                   <b>Hallo - </b>${snap.data().content}<br>
                                </p>`
      };
      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
          if (error) {
              console.log(error)
              return
          }
          console.log("sent")
      });
    };

    });
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get `email1`, and `email2` , ... properties, you can do as below

```
to: snap.data()['email'+i],
```

also to have better code, you can store `snap.data()` into a variable like

```
const data = snap.data();
```

and use it over and over like

```
to: data['email'+i]
```

Also you have `return` in your loop, it means after first one it will exit loop

### Suggestion

You can store emails as an array, instead of one by one, then you can simply loop through and send emails, also then you don't need number, so you shape of data will be like

```
{
  content: string;
  name: string;
  emails: string[];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But still it sents only email1 not email2

Comment: because you have `return ` in your for loop

Comment: thank you so much I put the return to the end of the code or should I just leave it out

Comment: don't need a return